# Are there currently any international ferries that travel to Saint Petersburg, Russia?

Tags: international-travel, russia, ferries, saint-petersburg

Years ago I was in Europe and decided it would be a great idea to go to Saint Petersburg by ferry since it is regarded as a beautiful city and is a port. I didn't mind departing from Finland, Estonia, or pretty much anywhere else. I only wanted to arrive by sea as this was the whole point.

I could not find at the time details on the Internet, Lonely Planet, Rough Guide, or travel agencies about where to depart from or if any international ferries even existed. Finally I found out there were none.

This was in 2001. Has the situation changed in the past ten years?

Comment: Related: [In St-Petersburg by ship on football WC-2018 site](http://welcome2018.com/en/transport/inter/saint-petersburg/by-ship/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, the situation has greatly changed since 2001 :)

Today you can get into Saint Petersburg in many ways by ferry:

1. By St. Peterline company ferries:

   1. by ["Princess Maria"](http://www.stpeterline.com/en/Schedule.aspx)

      - Monday, Thursday, Saturday at **19:00 from Helsinki** (you'll be at St-Petersburg at **09:30 AM next day**)
   2. by ["Princess Anastasia"](http://anastasia.stpeterline.com/ru/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.aspx) (sorry, only link in Russian are available)

      - Wednesday, **09:00 AM from Stockholm** without going through Tallinn's port (you'll be at St. Petersburg at **11:30 AM next day**)
      - Saturday, **19:00 from Stockholm** with visiting the Tallinn
      - Sunday, **18:00 from Tallinn** (you'll be at St.Petersburg at **8:00 AM next day**)
2. By AS Tallink Grupp company ferries (with changes):

   1. From [Riga](http://www.tallinksilja.com/en/web/int/stockholm-riga) you can go to Stockholm, after that use first variant
   2. From [Rostok](http://www.tallinksilja.com/en/schedules/helRos/) you can go to Helsinki, after that use the first variant
3. There is also [Viking Line](http://www.sales.vikingline.com/en/international/find-your-trip/timetables/helsinki-tallinn-/), [Eckero Line](https://www.eckeroline.fi/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Content_10151_10001_-1?page=index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D182%26lang%3Den-GB&smi=193&menuid=165&storeId=10151) and [Linda line](http://www.lindaline.fi/en/?p=1360&op=256) ferries, if the schedule of two first variants is not applicable, but you'll also need changes.
4. I found the [Finnlines](http://www.finnlines.com/ferry-trips/routes_fares) company, and they are serving many interesting routes in Baltic sea:

   1. You can get to Helsinki from [Gdynia](http://www.finnlines.com/ferry-trips/routes_fares/gdynia_helsinki), [Travemünde](http://www.finnlines.com/ferry-trips/routes_fares/helsinki_travemuende) or [Rostok](http://www.finnlines.com/ferry-trips/routes_fares/helsinki_rostock), and after that use the first variant.
   2. You can directly get [to the Saint-Petersburg](http://www.finnlines.com/ferry-trips/routes_fares/luebeck_st_petersburg) from Lübeck or Sassnitz in Germany, or from Ventspils in Latvia:

      - Wednesday, **19:00 from Lübeck** (you'll be at Sassnitz at **05:00 AM at Thursday**, departure at **07:15 AM**, at Ventspils at **Friday 00:00 AM / 04:00 AM**, and finally at Saint-Petersburg at **Saturday, 08:00 AM**)
      - Saturday, **19:00 from Lübeck** (you'll be at Ventspils (no stopover in Sassnitz) at **Monday 22:00 AM / 00:00 AM**, and at Saint-Petersburg at **Tuesday, 08:00 AM**)

---

Update: I strongly recommend minimizing travel time on Russian ships, mainly because of their service level. Ferries are old German ships, and servicemen are not as positive as on Finnish lines.
**Please do not think this relates to Saint Petersburg** where service has highly improved in the last 10 years.

---

Update 2: Added information about another ferry from Germany via Latvia by **Finnlines**.

Comment: Having just been to Tallinn, Helsinki and St Petersburg, I'd love to return and do what  you're looking at - arriving by ferry.  I entered Russia up north by Murmansk, so not this time.

Comment: You can move out of Russia in any point, can't you?

Comment: Do you have the times it takes for the crossings or the arrival times? The Helsinki and Tallinn options sound great.

Comment: @hippietrail updated the question with timetables.

Comment: @VMAtm: I would upvote again if I could!

Comment: You are welcome. I'll do my best to provide answers that helps you to visit my country :)

Comment: @VMATM - yes, I exited into Kazakhstan, I have a double entry but will reenter into Siberia (Novosobirsk) and head across to Mongolia.  Perhaps next year... :)

Comment: @Mark Mayo Well, this is amazing adventure. Good luck with that