# Applying for a Russian visa in Estonia for someone not yet in Estonia?

Tags: visas, russia, estonia, irish-citizens

I want to apply for two visas together, staying at the same accommodation (my name on the booking, other person's name does not appear). We are both Irish citizens but I currently live in Estonia, my friend is traveling here but I would like to arrange everything before they arrive.

Is it possible to apply for both before they arrive? What do I need to do? How long will it take?

It's just a 48 hour visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can manage out some kind of document from notaries says that your friend delegating you the right to provide the documents for visa application, but it still has to be an [**original of his passport**](http://www.ifs-estonia.com/page/500?domain=16&language=41) in your hands, as the visa is being posted in the passport:

> 1. A valid original passport, which has no less than **2 blank visa pages**. The passport must be valid for **6 months after the date of visa expiration**;

Prices for **30** day visa with a tourism purpose is `35 + 21 EUR`, and it will be done in 10 calendar days (so, it's about 2 business weeks). In case you need it in a hurry, you may apply for urgent **30** day visa with a tourism purpose, but this will cost you a `70 + 21 EUR`, and it will be done in 3 days (visa is valid starting from the 4th day).

What you can do for save your time is to [arrange the appointment in Russian Embassy](http://www.ifs-estonia.com/page/524?domain=16&language=42)

Note that there is an exception from visa for cruise ship passengers, who spend **less than 72 hours in Russia**, but in this case you will be limited in places you can go in participating cities (for Baltic sea they are Kaliningrad and Saint-Petersburg).

I found some other site for getting the visa for [4 days with touristic purposes](http://www.viisa.ee/en/services/visa-issuing/visa-to-russia), but it seems like a travel agency, as their prices are a bit bigger than official ones ([link in Russian](http://www.viisa.ee/ru/nashi-uslugi/ofofrmlenie-viz/viza-v-rossiju)).

Comment: The cruise ship seems like a great option but the only one I could find goes clockwise around the baltic, meaning I'd have to go to Stockholm and Helsinki first.

Comment: [There is a ferry from Tallinn to Saint Petersburg](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91158/ferry-system-from-st-petersburg-to-tallin-and-helsinki), after that it goes to Helsinki, from which you can go directly back to Tallinn.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane but you should investigate the route across the city, as it is very limited with no opportunity to book a hotel - you have to sleep at ferry

Comment: Thanks but that just kind of confirmed what I was saying.

Tallin-Stockholm-Helsinki-St.Petersburg 
Departure 24.04.2017 18:30
Arrival 27.04.2017 09:00
Duration 62h 30min

Comment: Oh, I got this, they switched the route :( there was one with a return from Tallinn to Saint Petersburg :(